# ¿Cómo cambiar el alto de un contenedor según el slide que este activo al momento de hacer swipe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, materialize

Estoy utilizando Materialize y su función de Tabs - Swipeable, pero lo que hace es encerrar a los slide en posición absoluta y al contenedor se le tiene que definir un alto exacto.

Quiero que al cambiar de Tab, el contenedor padre obtenga el alto del slide activo pata que se vea bien tanto al dar click en un tab o deslizándo los slides.

He logrado realizar esto pero solo al hacer click en los tabs con el siguiente código jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Esta es la función que activa el deslizamiento de tabs - descomentar para que funcione
    //$('.tabs').tabs({
     //swipeable: true
    //});

    var caruHeight = $('.tabs-content .carousel-item:first').height();
 $('.tabs-content').height(caruHeight);
    $('ul.tabs > li.tab > a').click(function(){
     var idHref = $(this).attr('href');
     var caruHeight = $(idHref).height();
     $('.tabs-content').height(caruHeight);
    });
});
```

```css
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: 55px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
ul.tabs > li.tab {
    width: 20%;
}
ul.tabs > li.tab > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1px 0;
    position: relative;
}
ul.tabs > li.tab > a.active:after {
 content: '';
    background-image: url(../images/bg-arrow-tabs-topbar.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 28px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
ul.navPoderes > li.tab > a span {
    display: block;
}
ul.navPoderes > li.tab > a span.icon-poder {
    height: 37px;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
ul.navPoderes > li.tab > a.active span.icon-poder {
    height: 53px;
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    margin: 0;
}
ul.navPoderes > li.tab > a span.icon-poder > img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: inherit;
}
ul.navPoderes > li.tab > a span.poder-name {
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #A6A6A6;
}
ul.navPoderes > li.tab > a.active span.poder-name {
 display: none;
}
.tabs-content.carousel.carousel-slider .carousel-item {
    height: auto;
    min-height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.gradText-blue {
    background: linear-gradient(150deg, #3ac0f3, #076bae 80%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}
.gradText-yellow {
    background: linear-gradient(150deg, #fcec07, #ed8030 80%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}
.gradText-red {
    background: linear-gradient(150deg, #fe0000, #c60000 80%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}
.gradText-grey {
 background: linear-gradient(150deg, #a5a5a5, #4e4e4e 80%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}
.u-info-poder {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}
.u-info-poder > .uipoderbox {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    padding-right: 0;
    height: 45px;
    min-width: 70px;
    border-right: 2px solid #F2F2F2;
}
.u-info-poder > .uipoderbox.user-poder {
 padding-top: 8px;
}
.u-info-poder > .uipoderbox > span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.u-info-poder > .uipoderbox > span.ui-photo {
    width: 32px;
}
.u-info-poder > .uipoderbox > span.ui-photo img {
    display: block;
}
.u-info-poder > .uipoderbox > span.ui-name-poder {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 18px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#Poder-Terricola span.ui-name-poder {
    color: #7F7F7F;
}
.u-info-poder > .uipoderbox > span.icon-star {
    width: 30px;
}
.u-info-poder > .uipoderbox > span.ui-icon-poder {
    height: 35px;
}
.u-info-poder > .uipoderbox > span.ui-icon-poder > img {
 height: inherit;
}
.u-info-earn {
    background: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 9px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.u-info-earn > div {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 4px 18px;
}
.u-info-earn > div.coins-earn {
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-right: 16px;
}
.u-info-earn > div > span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.u-info-earn > .solve-earn > span.icon-earnbox {
    height: 14px;
}
.u-info-earn > .coins-earn > span.icon-earnbox {
    height: 28px;
}
.u-info-earn > div > span.icon-earnbox > img {
    display: block;
    height: inherit;
}
.u-info-earn > div > span.numcoins-earnbox {
    margin: 0 7px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.u-info-earn > div > .txt-earnbox {
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 9px;
    color: #A6A6A6;
}
.content-poder {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.content-poder section {margin-bottom: 15px;}
.sec-content {
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.sec-content.soon {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #A6A6A6;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    min-height: 100px;
    align-items: center;
}
.title-secpoder {
    background: #D9D9D9;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.title-secpoder > img {
    height: 23px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.sec-cursos .icon-widitem {
 background: linear-gradient(0deg, #3ac0f3, #076bae);
}
.widitem {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.widitem > .box {
    max-width: 110px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.widitem .icon-widitem {
    max-width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 8px solid #F2F2F2;
    padding: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 55px;
}
.widitem .icon-widitem span.poder-curso {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    bottom: -18px;
    right: -20px;
}
.widitem .title-widitem {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #A6A6A6;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.w-100 {
    width: 100%;
}
.curso-requisitos {
 border-radius: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 280px;
    min-width: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #3ac0f3, #076bae);
}
.head-req {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.head-req span.cant-req {
    float: right;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
.content-req {
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.content-req > div {
    width: 26%;
}
.content-req > .info-req {
    width: 48%;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.content-req > .info-req > span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20%;
}
.content-req > .info-req > .txt-req {
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 75%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.content-req > .state-req {
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 55px;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.content-req > .state-req > img {
    height: 26px;
}
.content-req > .icon-req > img {
    height: 26px;
}
.foot-req > .poderUp-req {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: #2eace3;
}
.foot-req > .viewtem-req {
 font-weight: lighter;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>tabs</title>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="tabs-topbar">
  <ul class="tabs flexbox navPoderes">
      <li class="tab"><a href="#Poder-Terricola">
       <span class="icon-poder"><img src="images/p_terricola_trazo.png" alt=""></span>
       <span class="poder-name">terrícola</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#Poder-Super">
       <span class="icon-poder"><img src="images/p_sayayin_trazo.png" alt=""></span>
       <span class="poder-name">super</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#Poder-Dios">
       <span class="icon-poder"><img src="images/p_dios_trazo.png" alt=""></span>
       <span class="poder-name">dios</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#Poder-Blue">
       <span class="icon-poder"><img src="images/p_blue_trazo.png" alt=""></span>
       <span class="poder-name">blue</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#Poder-Instinto">
       <span class="icon-poder"><img src="images/p_instinto_trazo.png" alt=""></span>
       <span class="poder-name">instinto</span></a>
      </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <!-- Fin tabs-topbar - Barra de Navegación -->

 <!-- Poderes -->
 <main id="Poderes" class="bg-white">
  <div id="Poder-Terricola">
   <div class="head-poder">
    <div class="flexbox u-info-poder">
     <div class="uipoderbox user-poder">
      <span class="ui-photo"><img src="images/foto_1.png" alt=""></span>
      <span class="ui-name-poder">Poder Terrícola</span>
     </div>
     <div class="uipoderbox">
      <span class="rank-poder gradText-yellow">4.6</span>
      <span class="icon-star"><img src="images/icon-star-perfil.png" alt=""></span>
     </div>
     <div class="uipoderbox"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox u-info-earn">
     <div class="solve-earn">
      <span class="icon-earnbox"><img src="images/icon-solve-earn-poderes.png" alt=""></span>
      <span class="numcoins-earnbox gradText-blue">180</span>
      <span class="txt-earnbox">problemas<br>que resolví</span>
     </div>
     <div class="coins-earn">
      <span class="icon-earnbox"><img src="images/icon-coins-earn-poderes.png" alt=""></span>
      <span class="numcoins-earnbox gradText-yellow">2000</span>
      <span class="txt-earnbox">coins</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="content-poder">
    <section>
     <h6 class="title-secpoder">Beneficios para Ti</h6>
     <div class="flexbox sec-content">
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-problemas-perfil.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Publica tus Problemas</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-descargado-perfil.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Contenido Personalizado</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem w-100">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-busca-soluciones.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Busca Soluciones</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem w-100">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-medir-progreso.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Mide tu Progreso</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="Poder-Super">
   <div class="head-poder">
    <div class="flexbox u-info-poder">
     <div class="uipoderbox user-poder">
      <span class="ui-photo"><img src="images/foto_1.png" alt=""></span>
      <span class="ui-name-poder gradText-yellow">Poder Super</span>
     </div>
     <div class="uipoderbox">
      <span class="rank-poder gradText-yellow">4.6</span>
      <span class="icon-star"><img src="images/icon-star-perfil.png" alt=""></span>
     </div>
     <div class="uipoderbox">
      <span class="ui-num-poder gradText-yellow">1</span>
      <span class="ui-icon-poder"><img src="images/p_sayayin_trazo.png" alt=""></span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox u-info-earn">
     <div class="solve-earn">
      <span class="icon-earnbox"><img src="images/icon-solve-earn-poderes.png" alt=""></span>
      <span class="numcoins-earnbox gradText-blue">180</span>
      <span class="txt-earnbox">problemas<br>que resolví</span>
     </div>
     <div class="coins-earn">
      <span class="icon-earnbox"><img src="images/icon-coins-earn-poderes.png" alt=""></span>
      <span class="numcoins-earnbox gradText-yellow">2000</span>
      <span class="txt-earnbox">coins</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="content-poder">
    <section>
     <h6 class="title-secpoder">Beneficios Adicionales</h6>
     <div class="flexbox sec-content">
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-solve-earn-poderes.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Entrena Resolviendo Problemas</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-premio-perfil.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Compite</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-felicity.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Gana<br> Premios</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
    <section>
     <h6 class="title-secpoder"><img src="images/icon-key-title.png" alt="">Aumenta Estos Poderes</h6>
     <div class="flexbox sec-content sec-cursos">
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-fx-cursos-poderes.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Matemático</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem">
         <img src="images/icon-board-cursos-poderes.png" alt="">
         <span class="poder-curso"><img src="images/p_sayayin_trazo.png" alt=""></span>
        </div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Físico</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem w-100">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-fx-cursos-poderes.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Químico</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="Poder-Dios">
   <div class="head-poder">
    <div class="flexbox u-info-poder">
     <div class="uipoderbox">
      <span class="ui-photo"><img src="images/foto_1.png" alt=""></span>
      <span class="ui-name-poder gradText-red">Poder Dios</span>
     </div>
     <div class="uipoderbox">
      <span class="rank-poder">4.6</span>
      <span class="icon-star"><img src="images/icon-star-perfil.png" alt=""></span>
     </div>
     <div class="uipoderbox">
      <span class="ui-num-poder gradText-red">0</span>
      <span class="ui-icon-poder"><img src="images/p_dios_trazo.png" alt=""></span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox u-info-earn">
     <div class="solve-earn">
      <span class="icon-earnbox"><img src="images/icon-solve-earn-poderes.png" alt=""></span>
      <span class="numcoins-earnbox gradText-blue">180</span>
      <span class="txt-earnbox">problemas<br>que resolví</span>
     </div>
     <div class="coins-earn">
      <span class="icon-earnbox"><img src="images/icon-coins-earn-poderes.png" alt=""></span>
      <span class="numcoins-earnbox gradText-yellow">2000</span>
      <span class="txt-earnbox">coins</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="content-poder">
    <section>
     <h6 class="title-secpoder">Beneficios Adicionales</h6>
     <div class="flexbox sec-content">
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-cotiza-problemas.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Cotiza Problemas</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-gana-dinero.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Gana Dinero</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-accede-cursos.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Accede a Más Cursos</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
    <section>
     <h6 class="title-secpoder"><img src="images/icon-key-title.png" alt="">Cursos Dios - Físico</h6>
     <div class="flexbox sec-content sec-cursos">
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-board-cursos-poderes.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Física 1</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-board-cursos-poderes.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Física 2</div>
        <div class="curso-requisitos">
         <h6 class="head-req">Requisitos <span class="cant-req"><span class="req-compl">2</span>/3</span></h6>
         <div class="site-req">
          <div class="flexbox content-req">
           <div class="info-req">
            <span class="num-req">1</span>
            <span class="txt-req">Score Mínimo <strong>4,0</strong> Stars</span>
           </div>
           <div class="state-req"><img src="images/icon-check-req.png" alt=""></div>
           <div class="icon-req"><img src="images/icon-star-req.png" alt=""></div>
          </div>
          <div class="flexbox content-req">
           <div class="info-req">
            <span class="num-req">2</span>
            <span class="txt-req">Resolver <strong>500</strong> Problemas</span>
           </div>
           <div class="state-req"><img src="images/icon-check-req.png" alt=""></div>
           <div class="icon-req"><img src="images/icon-camera-req.png" alt=""></div>
          </div>
          <div class="flexbox content-req">
           <div class="info-req">
            <span class="num-req">3</span>
            <span class="txt-req">Aprobar Test</span>
           </div>
           <div class="state-req">GO!</div>
           <div class="icon-req"><img src="images/icon-test-req.png" alt=""></div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="foot-req">
          <a href="#" class="btnfdex poderUp-req">Aumentar poder</a>
          <a href="#" class="viewtem-req">Ver Temario</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem w-100">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-board-cursos-poderes.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Física 3</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
    <section>
     <h6 class="title-secpoder"><img src="images/icon-key-title.png" alt="">Cursos Dios - Químico</h6>
     <div class="flexbox sec-content sec-cursos">
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-fx-cursos-poderes.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Química Orgánica</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-fx-cursos-poderes.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Química Inorgánica</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
    <section>
     <h6 class="title-secpoder"><img src="images/icon-key-title.png" alt="">Cursos Dios - Mate</h6>
     <div class="flexbox sec-content sec-cursos">
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-fx-cursos-poderes.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Mate 1</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-fx-cursos-poderes.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Mate 2</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem w-100">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-fx-cursos-poderes.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Mate<br> Básica 1</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-fx-cursos-poderes.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Cálculo 1</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-fx-cursos-poderes.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Cálculo 2</div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widitem">
       <div class="box">
        <div class="icon-widitem"><img src="images/icon-fx-cursos-poderes.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title-widitem">Cálculo 3</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="Poder-Blue">
   <div class="head-poder">
    <div class="flexbox u-info-poder">
     <div class="uipoderbox">
      <span class="ui-photo"><img src="images/foto_1.png" alt=""></span>
      <span class="ui-name-poder gradText-blue">Poder Blue</span>
     </div>
     <div class="uipoderbox">
      <span class="rank-poder">4.6</span>
      <span class="icon-star"><img src="images/icon-star-perfil.png" alt=""></span>
     </div>
     <div class="uipoderbox">
      <span class="ui-num-poder gradText-blue">0</span>
      <span class="ui-icon-poder"><img src="images/p_blue_trazo.png" alt=""></span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox u-info-earn">
     <div class="solve-earn">
      <span class="icon-earnbox"><img src="images/icon-solve-earn-poderes.png" alt=""></span>
      <span class="numcoins-earnbox gradText-blue">180</span>
      <span class="txt-earnbox">problemas<br>que resolví</span>
     </div>
     <div class="coins-earn">
      <span class="icon-earnbox"><img src="images/icon-coins-earn-poderes.png" alt=""></span>
      <span class="numcoins-earnbox gradText-yellow">2000</span>
      <span class="txt-earnbox">coins</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="content-poder">
    <section>
     <h6 class="title-secpoder">Beneficios Adicionales</h6>
     <div class="flexbox sec-content soon">
      Próximamente
     </div>
    </section>
    <section>
     <h6 class="title-secpoder"><img src="images/icon-key-title.png" alt="">Cursos Dios - Físico</h6>
     <div class="flexbox sec-content soon">
      Próximamente
     </div>
    </section>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="Poder-Instinto">
   <div class="head-poder">
    <div class="flexbox u-info-poder">
     <div class="uipoderbox">
      <span class="ui-photo"><img src="images/foto_1.png" alt=""></span>
      <span class="ui-name-poder gradText-grey">Poder Instinto</span>
     </div>
     <div class="uipoderbox">
      <span class="rank-poder gradText-yellow">4.6</span>
      <span class="icon-star"><img src="images/icon-star-perfil.png" alt=""></span>
     </div>
     <div class="uipoderbox">
      <span class="ui-num-poder gradText-grey">0</span>
      <span class="ui-icon-poder"><img src="images/p_instinto_trazo.png" alt=""></span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox u-info-earn">
     <div class="solve-earn">
      <span class="icon-earnbox"><img src="images/icon-solve-earn-poderes.png" alt=""></span>
      <span class="numcoins-earnbox gradText-blue">180</span>
      <span class="txt-earnbox">problemas<br>que resolví</span>
     </div>
     <div class="coins-earn">
      <span class="icon-earnbox"><img src="images/icon-coins-earn-poderes.png" alt=""></span>
      <span class="numcoins-earnbox gradText-yellow">2000</span>
      <span class="txt-earnbox">coins</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="content-poder">
    <section>
     <h6 class="title-secpoder">Beneficios Adicionales</h6>
     <div class="flexbox sec-content soon">
      Próximamente
     </div>
    </section>
    <section>
     <h6 class="title-secpoder"><img src="images/icon-key-title.png" alt="">Cursos Dios - Físico</h6>
     <div class="flexbox sec-content soon">
      Próximamente
     </div>
    </section>
   </div>
  </div>
 </main>

 <!-- Scripts - Archivos JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Fin Scripts - Archivos JavaScript -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Fernando, el sistema marco tu pregunta como "demasiada extensa" posiblemente por la cantidad de código en la misma, revisa [ask] para encontrar información que ayudará a realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtener excelentes respuestas. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio, saludos.